# ASP.net, Redirect fine on localhost, but won't redirect on webhost

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i am facing a strange problem.

I am trying to navigate to a page after session timeout. It's working very good on my localhost, it's able to redirect to a choosen page. But it won't on the webhost :/

anyone can help?

here is my code:

```
  if (remainingTime >= 0) {
            displaySessionTimeout()
        } else {                
            PageMethods.SendStatusToDB(OnSuccess);

            function OnSuccess() {

                clearInterval(intervalHandle);

                window.location = "http://zaghilionheart.com/GreenhouseHomepage.aspx";


            }



        }
```

Comment: have you checked for errors? in chrome you can open Developer Tools and in the Console tab the errors are displayed.

Comment: here is the error i get:
Uncaught Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'SendStatusToDB' failed with the following error: The requested resource could not be loaded because the server returned an error:<br> &nbsp; <b>404 No...<omitted>...>